# Why is Danbo so popular?

Tags: culture, yotsubato

Originally, Danbo was a cardboard box robot from the manga Yotsuba&!.

[image: cover of volume 5 of Yotsuba&!, featuring Danbo and Yotsuba]

But most people recognize Danbo from a photo-shot (that's how I knew of Danbo before I finally read the manga) and if you try to [google image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=danbo&es_sm=93&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=NzGGU-3fEdeNuASemoHoAw&ved=0CDwQsAQ&biw=1242&bih=585#q=danbo&tbm=isch&tbs=isz:m) it, the result will be something like this, not the Yotsuba&! manga.

[image: photograph of Danbo]

So how could Danbo become so popular? Is there someone who used it for advertising or something?

Comment: "Danbooru" means cardboard, which this guy is made of.

Comment: you can see on the small danbo "amazon.co.jp", and I think I've seen that association a lot, so maybe they pushed the character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Kaiyodo began selling Danbo models, a photographer named Arielle Nasal began taking photos of them every day for a year

[See her account here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/bunnyrel/sets/72157615647396658/)

These photos were eventually compiled into a book "365 Days of Danboard"

[image]

This piece is the source of many danbo scenic photographs, and the inspiration for others

After this, there were many Danbo photographs being taken. Many Facebook, Tumble and Flicker pages set up with Danbo photos as their focus. Most notable of these is the [Danbo Love Flickr group](https://www.flickr.com/groups/danbo-love/) who have amassed a staggering 35,000 photos of Danbo

There are 4 different models of Danbo available at time of writing - Original, Amazon.JP branded, 7/11 Branded, Miniature